pytorch error: Inference tensors cannot be saved for backward. To work around you can make a clone to get a normal tensor and use it in autograd
trying to finetune a model but gives this error when training it.
here's the Jupyter cell that gives me this error:
training_args = transformers.TrainingArguments(
      per_device_train_batch_size=1,
      gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
      num_train_epochs=1,
      learning_rate=2e-4,
      fp16=True,
      save_total_limit=3,
      logging_steps=1,
      output_dir="experiments",
      optim="paged_adamw_8bit",
      lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
      warmup_ratio=0.05,
)

trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=data,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False)
)


model.config.use_cache = False
trainer.train()


i tried changing torch.inference_mode() with torch.no_grad() earlier in the code but that doesn't work, tried to change some parameters, which doesn't work too, and when the usecache is =True it says the list is out of tuple which might be expected?
also tried insantiating the model again before optimizing, that doesn't work too. Keep in mind this code used to work, which makes me think if there's an update on the libraries that i'm using or maybe on the model that im training?

When you change from torch.inference_mode() to torch.no_grad(), you need to Delete the runtime and restart the session, I've got the same error here and I fixed it.

hey! I think there was an error with my datafile, I already tried restarting, but thank you sm for the answer! :)
